# Select2 automatically adding blank value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select2-rails

I'm using select2 for a multiple selector. Currently this is in my HTML file:

```
 <%= form.select "page_request_set_ids", @multiautocomplete_set_options.unshift(""),
 {}, id: "page-request-sets", multiple: true,
 allowClear: true, data: {placeholder: "Start typing sets..."} %>
```

`@multiautocomplete_set_options` is an array of strings. 
When I go to access `:page_request_set_ids` later, the strings I typed in are there, along with an empty string.

I've tried to remove the `unshift("")`, which kept my placeholder, but did not remove the issue of the blank string in `:page_request_set_ids`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Directly taken from the `select` [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select):

**Gotcha**

The HTML specification says when multiple parameter passed to select and all options got deselected web browsers do not send any value to server. Unfortunately this introduces a gotcha: if an User model has many roles and have role_ids accessor, and in the form that edits roles of the user the user deselects all roles from role_ids multiple select box, no role_ids parameter is sent. So, any mass-assignment idiom like

```
@user.update(params[:user])
```

wouldn't update roles.

To prevent this the helper generates an auxiliary hidden field before every multiple select. The hidden field has the same name as multiple select and blank value.

Note: The client either sends only the hidden field (representing the deselected multiple select box), or both fields. This means that the resulting array always contains a blank string.

In case if you don't want the helper to generate this hidden field you can specify `include_hidden: false` option.

So bottom line is to add:

`include_hidden: false`

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I didn't pass the 'multiple: true' option to the select_tag in my erb/haml, and only set the option in select2 when initializing.

Make sure you have the option in both places.